# Cannot access to IP CAM flux (tp-link NC250), using python + opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I cannot access to IP CAM flux using python + opencv.
Tested opencv tutorial : no connection (gray frame).
Camera tested with zoneminder: works
Code tested with webcam : works
Tested with model : TPLINK NC200 and NC250, doesn't work

Camera model : TP-LINK, NC-250
adress to flux (mjepg H264) : "http://admin:<*password coded base 64*>@192.168.0.69:8080/stream/video/mjpeg"

code :

```
def Camera2(self, evt):
  while(True):
    try :
        test2 = "http://admin:<*password coded base 64*>@192.168.0.69:8080/stream/video/mjpeg"
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture('test2')

    except IOError:
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self,u"Pas de connection avec la caméra..",
                               u"Erreur connection", style = wx.OK)
        retour = dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()

    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # ouverture en volant
    img = cv2.imread(frame, -1)

    #img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.namedWindow('Cam2', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.resizeWindow('Cam2', config.largeur, config.hauteur)
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    text = str(u"Camera 2")
    cv2.putText(img, text, (5,40), font, 1, (255,255,255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.imshow('Cam2',img)
    #cv2.MoveWindow('Cam', 200, 600)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        print 'break imshow'
        cv2.destroyAllWindows('Cam2')
        break

    # rafraichissement
    time.sleep(config.fps)

print 'sorti de Cam2 !'
```

Is it a problem in my code, the codec of the flux or in the hardware of the camera ?

Somebody tested with another model ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved accessibility with **python-vlc** library, and directs links to snapshot returning a jpg file.